# how to Upload any type of files asp.net VB web

Tags: vb.net, iis, web-applications, bootstrap-4

I have upload files. 
this is my upload button:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-file">
<input type= "file"name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FileUpload1"id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload1">
<img src="../images/pngformat/attachment.png">  Upload here...
</label>
</div>
```

It just uploads .Zip/.PDF and .JPG files. I need to upload any file format. My code is generated by VB .Net 4.5 and I use IIS 7

How to set upload any type of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use below code to upload any type of file using vb web application.

webform1.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" />

            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

webform1.aspx.vb code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteFile(ByVal strFileName As String)

        If strFileName.Trim().Length > 0 Then
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(strFileName)
            If (fi.Exists) Then    'if file exists, delete it
                fi.Delete()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim sFileDir As String = "D:\testupload\"
        Dim lMaxFileSize As Long = 409600



        'check that the file has been selected and it's a valid file
        If (Not File1.PostedFile Is Nothing) _
           And (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0) Then
            'determine file name
            Dim sFileName As String =
               System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName)
            Try
                If File1.PostedFile.ContentLength <= lMaxFileSize Then
                    'save file on disk
                    File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(sFileDir + sFileName)
                    lblMessage.Visible = True
                    lblMessage.Text = "File: " + sFileDir + sFileName +
                       " Uploaded Successfully"
                Else    'reject file
                    lblMessage.Visible = True
                    lblMessage.Text = "File Size if Over the Limit of " +
                       lMaxFileSize
                End If
            Catch exc As Exception    'in case of an error
                lblMessage.Visible = True
                lblMessage.Text = "An Error Occured. Please Try Again!"
                DeleteFile(sFileDir + sFileName)
            End Try
        Else
            lblMessage.Visible = True
            lblMessage.Text = "Nothing to upload. Please Try Again!"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

test sample:
[image]

Note: you could increase file upload file size a per your requirement.