How Can I Make My HTML Page Upload a PDF to my ASPX Page
Background
Application/Program: Lightweight Website (40,000 HTML Pages | 5 ASPX Pages)
Goal: HTML Functionality that sends Uploaded PDFs to an ASPX Page (for processing)
Problem: Uploaded PDFs Get Corrupted
Desire: Uncorrupted PDF Uploads

Tech Specs
Server Architecture: IIS 8.0 (Prod) | IIS 10.0 (Dev)
Client-Side: HTML; Javascript (Vanilla); AJAX
Server-Side: ASPX; Visual Basic
Connection/Communication: One Server/Domain (ie, the HTML pages are on the same website as the ASPX page)

Details
On my HTML page, I have a FileUpload control. I want website visitors to use that control to upload PDFs. I want to store those uploaded PDFs [directly] onto my server (in an actual directory).
To accomplish that, I want my HTML pages to "send" the users' uploaded PDFs to my ASPX page. Whereby my ASPX page will perform the file storage.
Unfortunately, these uploaded PDFs end up getting corrupted [upon server storage]. They get corrupted in the following ways:

The Uploaded PDFs Cannot Be Opened (typical error); or
The Uploaded PDFs are missing content (eg, no text/image/content whatsoever; missing metadata).


Code
HTML Page


<form>
  <label for="inptFl" id="inptLbl"></label>
  <input type="file" name="inptFlNm" id="inptFl" accept=".pdf, application/pdf" multiple onchange="PickFiles();" />
  <button type="button" onclick="PushToServer();" >Submit</button>
</form>



Javascript


function PickFiles() {
  const flLst = document.getElementById("inptFl").files;
  var otPtLbl = document.getElementById("inptLbl");
  const flRdr = new FileReader();

  flRdr.addEventListener("load", (evnt) => {
    otPtLbl.setAttribute("data-loadedSource", evnt.target.result);
  });

  flRdr.ReadAsDataURL(flLst[0]);
  //flRdr.readAsBinaryString(flLst[0]);
}

function PushToServer() {
  const ajaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let otPtLbl = document.getElementById("inptLbl");
  let datURL = otPtLbl.getAttribute("data-loadedSource");

  ajaxObj.open("POST", "/WriteHere.aspx", true);
  //ajaxObj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  ajaxObj.send(datURL);
  //ajaxObj.send(encodeURIComponent(datURL));
}



ASPX Code-Behind (VB.net)


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  Request.InputStream.Position = 0
  Dim strm = Request.InputStream
  Dim n = CInt(strm.Length)
  Dim arrStrm() As Byte
  ReDim arrStrm(n)

  Dim strmRd = strm.Read(arrStrm, 0, n)

  IO.File.WriteAllBytes("/Foldy/Filey.pdf", arrStrm)

End Sub



Troubleshooting
I've spent the past 3 days trying to solve this problem. My troubleshooting has included - but has not been limited to - the following:

Using different JS permutations of FileReader().readAsDataURL()
Using different JS permutations of FileReader().readAsBinaryString()
Using different JS permutations of FileReader().readAsArrayBuffer()
Using different JS permutations of enctype=multipart/form-data
Using different JS permutations of enctype=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Using different JS permutations of enctype=application/pdf; charset=x-user-defined-binary
Using different JS permutations of enctype=encodeURIComponent
Using different VB permutations of Request.InputStream.Position
Using different VB permutations of Request.InputStream.Read()
Using different VB permutations of Request.InputStream.ReadASync()
Scouring the web for help (especially StackOverflow.com)
Glancing into technology manuals (eg, The Complete Reference to IIS 6)


Edits
@Christopher suggested that a similar question might help me. That similar question can be found at this URL: How to Upload Any Type of Files ASP.Net VB Web. However, that question pertains to ASPX only (ie, it excludes HTML). My question differs from it because my functionality includes an HTML interface. So, although I've tried to use that suggested page, it hasn't helped me.

Request
May you please help me get my HTML-to-ASPX file upload functionality to work for uploaded PDFs?
Thank You

SOLUTION
HTML Page


<form method="post" action="/WriteHere.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="inptFl_Nm" id="inptFl" accept=".pdf, application/pdf" multiple />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



ASPX Page


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  Dim flLstng = Request.Files
  flLstng(0).SaveAs("\Foldy\Filey.pdf")

End Sub



The keys to this solution were:

the enctype="multipart/form-data" HTML Form property;
the Request.Files(i).SaveAs() VB.net method; and
recognizing that HTML Forms can automatically populate the Request.Files` collection

I think this is a unique solution, because it's the only implementation that:

uses Vanilla JS (in fact, JS can be avoided altogether);
uses VB.net;
deals with an HTML-to-ASPX file transfer;  and
is elegant/concise (2 lines of code; 2 lines of HTML).

Well, I hope this can help you. It's certainly been the solution that I wanted (which took 4 days to put together – after several other hurdles).


What is the difference between the original files and the uploaded file? For example, the file length could be wrong. Note that ReDim arrStrm(n) resizes the array to n + 1 elements, and often ReDim indicates a problem, such as it should have been declared at the required size in the first place: Dim arrStrm(n - 1) As Byte.

@Andrew: There's no difference. I used the ReDim as a quick hack (to avoid IDE errors on Dim arrStrm(n) as Byte). I needed the hackjob because I had adapted my code from a C# subroutine. Nevertheless, I believe I've solved my problem (thanks to @Christopher). I'm working on fleshing out the full codeset right now. I'll post an update once I'm done (≈ on-or-before tomorrow – 12/10/24).

@Christopher: Thank You. I think your redirect (to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153139/how-to-upload-any-type-of-files-asp-net-vb-web) has actually led to my solution. The key to my solution was: (i) starting from scratch; (ii) understanding the HTTPPostedFile class; (iii) using the PostedFile.SaveAs() method; and – of course – (iv) realizing that HTML pages can send Request.Files collections to ASPX pages. Once I'm done fleshing out my solution, I'll post an update. I'd like to give you credit, especially since I believe my question is an important variant. Thx.
